# Dimension and smoothness of a variety after field extension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $X$ be an irreducible variety over $K$. Let $K \subseteq L$ be a field extension.
I am looking for a reference of the following facts:

-The dimension of every irreducible component of $X_L$ is $\dim X$.

-A point  $x \in X$ is smooth if and only if every point of $X_L$ lying over $x$ is smooth.

I have been looking in various books, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: Yes you are. $L[X]/PL[X]$ is not necessarily a domain. Take $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{C}$ and $P=(X^{2}+1)$. @Hans: For the stuff on smoothness, I like the discussion in Görtz, Wedhorn very much. But you will find this in many introductory books

Comment: yes, Görtz and Wedhorn is good for the smoothness, thx. and I also found a reference for the other question in the book!